# Checking local storage for each item in Flatlist and showing Icon depending on result REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native, local-storage, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I'm reading data from an api and showing this data in a flatlist, this data is a bunch of documents, whenever the user presses on any item it takes him to that document and I download this document so that the user can read it in offline mode. What i'm trying to do now is to show from the flatlist next to each entity if this file is downloaded or not. I already know how to check if files exist or not and m getting the correct result, but m not being capable to show the corresponding icon in the flatlist.

Code to check for files:

```
checkFiles = (file) => {
const url = file
let fileName = file.split('/')[5]
RNFS.mkdir(`${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}` + '/Duaas')
let localFile = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}` + '/Duaas/' + fileName;

RNFS.exists(localFile).then(async exists => {
  if (!exists) {
    return <Icon name={"file-download"} size={20} color={'#94b4ec'} />
  } else {
    return <Icon name={"file-download-done"} size={20} color={'#94b4ec'} />
  }
    })
  }
```

Code where i'm calling the function:

```
returnDoaa = (obj) => {
    return <TouchableOpacity disabled={this.state.loading} style={{ marginVertical: 5 }}
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DoaaDetails', { file: Server.getUrl(obj.item.file), title: obj.item.title, updatedAt: obj.item.updatedAt })}>
      <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
        {this.checkFiles(Server.getUrl(obj.item.file))}
        <SkeletonContent
          key={obj.item.id}
          containerStyle={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", alignItems: 'center' }}
          isLoading={this.state.loading}
          layout={[
            { key: obj.item.id, width: 200, height: 10, },
          ]}
        >
          <Text style={styles.rowText}>{obj.item.title}</Text>
        </SkeletonContent>
        {this.state.loading != true && <View style={styles.rightView}>
          <Image tintColor={Color.black} style={{ height: 10, width: 10 }} resizeMode="contain" source={require('../../images/backArrowBlack.png')} />
        </View>}
      </View>
      <View style={{ borderColor: Color.silver, borderTopWidth: 0.6 }}></View>
     </TouchableOpacity>
      }
```

If I make the checkFiles method return the icon directly it shows it, but when i add the code to check if file exists or not it shows nothing. So how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution i used was to alter the checkFiles method to update the state where m saving the documents, like this:

```
   async checkFiles() {
    for (const duaa of this.state.doaas) {
    const url = Server.getPhotoUrl(duaa.file)
    let fileName = Server.getPhotoUrl(duaa.file).split('/')[5]
    RNFS.mkdir(`${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}` + '/Duaas')
    let localFile = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}` + '/Duaas/' + fileName;

    RNFS.exists(localFile).then(async exists => {
      if (!exists) {
        this.updateStorageState(duaa, false)
      } else {
        this.updateStorageState(duaa, true)
      }
    })}
  }

  updateStorageState(duaa, exists) {
    updatedDuaas = this.state.doaas.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === duaa.id) {
        return {
          ...item,
          downloaded: exists
        }
      }
      return item
    })
    this.setState({ doaas: updatedDuaas})
  }
```

and in the returnDoaa method I set the icon condition based on the state, like this:

```
   returnDoaa = (obj) => {
    return <TouchableOpacity disabled={this.state.loading} style={{ marginVertical: 5 }}
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DoaaDetails', { file: Server.getUrl(obj.item.file), title: obj.item.title, updatedAt: obj.item.updatedAt })}>
      <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
        <SkeletonContent
          key={obj.item.id}
          containerStyle={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", alignItems: 'center' }}
          isLoading={this.state.loading}
          layout={[
            { key: obj.item.id, width: 200, height: 10, },
          ]}
        >
          {obj.item.downloaded ? <Icon name={"file-download-done"} size={20} color={'#94b4ec'} /> : <Icon name={"file-download"} size={20} color={'#94b4ec'} />}
          <Text style={styles.rowText}>{obj.item.title}</Text>
        </SkeletonContent>
        {this.state.loading != true && <View style={styles.rightView}>
          <Image tintColor={Color.black} style={{ height: 10, width: 10 }} resizeMode="contain" source={require('../../images/backArrowBlack.png')} />
        </View>}
      </View>
      <View style={{ borderColor: Color.silver, borderTopWidth: 0.6 }}></View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  }
```